# BigQuery slower than SQL Server

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, datamart

I am comparing query execution times in my data marts between SQL Server 2016 (Star Schema and using column based clustered index) and BigQuery (one single table)..I have around 20 million entries. Here is my query - I need month wise Sum of Oil, Gas, Water volumes. I have per day single entry of volumes for 10 years. I have 6500 entities and for each entity there is single entry of oil, gas, water volumes for 10 years..so total rows...6500(total entities) * 10(total years) * 365(total days)=23725000..ignore leap years for now

BigQuery - legacy SQL (taking 5 seconds)

```
SELECT [ASSET] AS [ASSET],
                  SUM([Measurements.GAS]) AS[sum_Measurements_GAS_ok],
                  SUM([Measurements.OIL]) AS[sum_Measurements_OIL_ok],
                  SUM([Measurements.WATER]) AS[sum_Measurements_WATER_ok],
                  STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP_TO_MSEC(Measurements.DATE)), '%Y-%m') as [month]
                FROM [datamanager-dashboard:bigquerysample.initial_va_schema_v3][initial_va_schema_v3]
                GROUP BY 1, 5
```

SQL Server 2016 - Star Schema (taking 2 seconds) - running inside VM in Google Compute Engine - n1-standard-4

```
SELECT [dim_asset_types].[asset_name] AS Asset,
            SUM([fact_well_volume_events].[gas]) AS [sum:gas:ok],
            SUM([fact_well_volume_events].[oil]) AS [sum:oil:ok],
            SUM([fact_well_volume_events].[water]) AS [sum:water:ok],
            DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [fact_well_volume_events].[measurement_date]), 0) AS [tmn:measurement_date:ok]
            FROM [dbo].[dim_asset_types] [dim_asset_types]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[xref_well_to_asset_type] [xref_well_to_asset_type] ON ([dim_asset_types].[dim_asset_type_key] = [xref_well_to_asset_type].[dim_asset_type_key])
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[dim_wells] [dim_wells] ON ([xref_well_to_asset_type].[dim_well_key] = [dim_wells].[dim_well_key])
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[fact_well_volume_events_with_calculations] [fact_well_volume_events] ON ([dim_wells].[dim_well_key] = [fact_well_volume_events].[dim_well_key])
            GROUP BY [dim_asset_types].[asset_name],DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [fact_well_volume_events].[measurement_date]), 0)
```

I gave single example only but it is happening with all sort of different queries. Am I missing something? Why BigQuery is so slow?

EDIT: I am attaching sample schema...its not full..

```
[
  {
    "name": "ASSET",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "name": "Measurements",
    "type": "record",
    "mode": "repeated",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "DATE",
        "type": "TIMESTAMP"
      },
      {
        "name": "OIL",
        "type": "FLOAT"
      },
      {
        "name": "WATER",
        "type": "FLOAT"
      },
      {
        "name": "GAS",
        "type": "FLOAT"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: For benchmarking, please be sure to use [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) in BigQuery as well. With that said, BigQuery's advantage is how well it handles concurrency and large queries, not how well it performs on small queries.

Comment: Are you saying it would be fast with with standard SQL? It's slow with standard SQL as well.

Comment: I'm saying that if you want to benchmark BigQuery, you should use the dialect where the team is actively making performance improvements. In terms of schema design, you may be better off with a nested schema instead of having multiple fact tables.

Comment: @Elliott...I have single schema with nested columns not multiple fact table...Multiple fact tables are there in SQL Server Star Schema...let me share performance numbers with Standard SQL as well...I have updated my question with minimal nested schema used in BigQuery

Comment: @ElliottBrossard...any idea? I need some help urgently that will help me to narrow down choices of my data mart to BigQuery...

Comment: I would really suggest [contacting sales](https://cloud.google.com/contact/), who are better at providing suggestions on this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery is not going to give you better results than SQL Server doing small queries over Datamarts. BigQuery works very well with huge queries but always have a fixed time of a few seconds. It needs to create an execution plan and distribute it in different machines and that needs time.

The difference between SQL Server and BigQuery is that you could run huge queries over your raw data (without Datamarts) and probably in queries that SQL Server could take minutes or hours, BigQuery is going to take less than a minute.